# galssfish local path configuration

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I want to set up a web application locally with glassfish4. I did all the necessary steps but when a I try to run the application I get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. My question is that how I can set up the right path to glassfish , to find my application

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. It's not clear what the "necessary steps" are that you did and there's no stack trace of the error. The `ClassNotFoundException` is somewhat useless without the rest of the error message.

Comment: As Mike said, you need to update your post with the stack trace. Nobody can solve your problem with the limited information you have provided so far. One other thing worth doing is to verify that Glassfish is running properly. Start Glassfish and then enter _http://localhost:8080/_ in your browser. Glassfish should display a screen with the message _"Your server is now running"_.